# Set a specific date retrieved from backend in Zebra Date picker dynamically

Tags: jquery

I am using Zebra Date Picker in my application and its good to use.

But now i am try to set a date dynamically when clicking a button.
I searched the web for any reference, but could not find any.

Please suggest any possible solution.

Reference : http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/zebra-datepicker/

Comment: Is your datepicker always visible or not?

Comment: Yes.. its always visible..
User can select a date and this will be saved in databse..
I am trying to set date which is retrieved from database, when user tries to edit the date..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I can see, it could be done like below:

```
$("#datepicker-example13").val('2012-12-23').data('Zebra_DatePicker').show();
```

This works fine on their page when I run it in console

Comment: Thanks.. its working great.
This will definitely help some one..